# Merging various road data into single layer using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, road, workflow

My company has two different road layers:

```
1) County roads
2) Old CAD roads
```

Each with their own pros and cons. I'm attempting to merge these into a single road layer that will be maintained.

The County has pretty good road data as far as location. It is also M-enabled for routing, which is nice. But it's missing road names.

Our CAD roads are dated and haven't been updated in a long time, but all the roads do have names.

My plan is to use the County roads as the base layer and try to join the CAD road names to it. But I first need to get them to line up correctly.

I believe the [Integrate tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000002s000000) will work, but I haven't used it yet.

But then I need join the CAD road names to the County roads and keep the output M-enabled.

Any tips?

Comment: I would be trying a spatial join. How close are they in terms of accuracy?

Comment: You might try to use the Snap geoprocessing tool to snap the CAD roads to your county if you don't really need the M enabled.  Although after doing that you might try the spatial join already suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Try:
Converting the CAD layer to a point feature (while maintaining attributes)
Spatial Join, with the County Roads line feature as target, and the new point feature from CAD as the join feature.
According to the Help file, A join point will be matched to the nearest target line within the search radius.

[ArcGIS 10.1 - Spatial joins by feature type](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s00000032000000)